# How to display a python function result in html

Tags: python, html

```
index.html
<select id="first">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
<select id="second">
    <option value="d">D</option>
    <option value="e">E</option>
</select>
<button id="submit_btn" type="button" onclick="convertFunction()">Convert</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
    const convert = {fir:document.getElementById("first"), sec:document.getElementById("second")}
    function convertFunction() {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = crpto.py.convert(convert.fir,convert.sec);
    }
</script>
```

There is only 1 function in crpto.py

```
crpto.py
def convert(first,second):
    ...do something here to convert the input to the result...
    return result
```

All I want is to get the value from HTML as the input variables, and send them in the python file and run its function, then return the result back to the HTML and display it.

I don't know how and what tool I should use, like Flask? Django? JQuery? JSON? AJAX?

Comment: you can use `flask` or `django` but you can't run python code in browser like this, however, tutorials on either of those frameworks cover how to send data via requests to the server side where you can handle them and return back

Comment: thanks, I'll look for that